# Spot light effect does not work correctly using GLSL shaders

Tags: opengl, glsl, opengl-3, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

I'm working on a personal graphic engine and I started to develop spot lights. The problem is the rendering is not logical. For a sake of simplicity I cleaned all informations about light and texture managing inside the shaders example below.

Here's the vertex shader code :

```
#version 400

layout (location = 0) in vec3 VertexPosition;

uniform mat4 ModelViewMatrix;
uniform mat4 MVP;

out vec3 VPosition;

void main(void)
{
    VPosition = vec3(ModelViewMatrix * vec4(VertexPosition, 1.0f));     //Eye coordinates vertex position
    gl_Position = MVP * vec4(VertexPosition, 1.0f);
}
```

And the fragment shader code :

```
#version 400

in vec3 Position;   //IN EYE COORDINATES

layout (location = 0) out vec4 FragColor;

uniform int lightCount;

struct SpotLight
{
    vec4 Position;      //ALREADY IN EYE COORDINATES
    vec3 La, Ld, Ls;
    vec3 direction;
    float exponent;
    float cutoff;
};

uniform SpotLight LightInfos[1];

vec3 getLightIntensity(void)
{
    vec3 LightIntensity = vec3(0.0f);

    for (int idx = 0; idx < lightCount; idx++)
    {
        vec3 lightDirNorm = normalize(vec3(LightInfos[idx].Position) - Position);
        vec3 spotDirNorm = normalize(LightInfos[idx].direction);
        float angle = acos(dot(-lightDirNorm, spotDirNorm));
        float cutoff = radians(clamp(LightInfos[idx].cutoff, 0.0f, 90.0f));

        vec3 ambient = vec3(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.8f);      //Color out of the spotlight's cone.
        vec3 spotColor = vec3(0.1f, 0.8f, 0.1f);    //Color within the spotlight's cone.

        if (angle < cutoff)
        {
            LightIntensity = spotColor;
        }
        else
        {
            LightIntensity = ambient;
        }
    }
    return (LightIntensity);
}

void main(void)
{
    FragColor = vec4(getLightIntensity(), 1.0f);
}
```

Here's the C++ code where I send the light position properties :

```
glm::vec4 lightPositionVec = viewMatrix * glm::vec4(lightPosition[0], lightPosition[1], lightPosition[2], lightPosition[3]);

program->setUniform(std::string("LightInfos[").append(Utils::toString<int>(idx)).append("].Position").c_str(), lightPositionVec);
```

Here's the spot light properties :

```
<position x="0.0" y="2.0" z="0.0" w="1" />
<direction x="0.0" y="-1.0" z="0.0" />
<exponent>3.0</exponent>
<cutoff>50.0</cutoff>
```

The view properties :

```
<camera name="cam1">
  <perspective fovy="70.0" ratio="1.0" nearClipPlane="0.1" farClipPlane="1000.0"/>
  <lookat>
     <eye x="0.0" y="50.0" z="50.0" />
     <target x="0.0" y="0.0" z="0.0" />
     <up x="0.0" y="1.0" z="0.0"/>
  </lookat>
</camera>
```

I checked these informations before sending them to the program shader in my C++ code and they are correct.

And here's the result :

[image]

And if I place the camera closer to the plane with the following camera properties :

```
 <camera name="cam1">
      <perspective fovy="70.0" ratio="1.0" nearClipPlane="0.1" farClipPlane="1000.0"/>
      <lookat>
         <eye x="0.0" y="10.0" z="20.0" />
         <target x="0.0" y="0.0" z="0.0" />
         <up x="0.0" y="1.0" z="0.0"/>
      </lookat>
    </camera>
```

the result is the following (closer to the reality but still not correct) :

[image]

As you can see, it's not logical : I have a spot in x=0, y=1, z=0, a downward spot light direction (x=0, y=-1, z=0) so I don't understand this result. Plus, all my vectors are in eye coordinates. I have the impression that the spot light effect depends the position of the camera. Does anyone can help me ?

Comment: And where do you transform the light parameters to eye coordinates?

Comment: In my C++ code. I updated the question. But the spot light position is correct because before to start spot lights I began by point lights and all is correct. Here the problem seems to comes from the computing of the 'angle' and 'cutoff' variable in the fragment shader.

Comment: `glm::vec4 lightPositionVec = viewMatrix * glm::vec4...` well this should be modelView matrix, to transform the light position to eye coordinates. Just btw you can use `LightInfos[idx].Position.xyz` instead of `vec3(LightInfos[idx].Position)`, it's usualy more readable :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I modified my code with the modelViewMatrix but it still the same display!

Comment: Do you also transform the light direction?

Comment: Thank you very much! I've forgotten to transform it. Bye.

Answer (score 1):

worked with several types of lights: directional, spotlight, point light

here is code

https://code.google.com/p/jpcsp/source/browse/trunk/src/jpcsp/graphics/shader.vert?r=1639

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GLSL_Programming/GLUT/Specular_Highlights

Comment: Avoid posting link-only answer. While they may be correct, your answer's integrity will be compromised should the link ever change/break. Try to include any relevant code from the links you posted.

Comment: Although what Tim says it is true, thanks for the second link, it is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Tim Lewis: ok next time will do.

Answer (score 0):

Is the problem the difference between

```
out vec3 VPosition;
```

and

```
in vec3 Position;
```